# json decoding with struct using swift4

Tags: json, struct, swift4, decodable

**JSON**

```
{
  "callBackID" : "add1867f-6005-189c-bbb4-ff53202b0697",
  "config" : {
    "description" : "Welcome Page",
    "show-bottom-bar" : "",
    "css-page-align" : "",
    "footer" : { "show" : "", "object" : "bottom-bar" },
    "pageStyle" : "full-page",
    "sourceType" : "list",
    "title" : "Welcome Page",
    "header" : { "show" : true, "hide" : false, "object" : "top-bar" },
    "columns" : {},
    "objects" : {},
    "showtabs" : true,
    "slides" : [{"title" : "first section","map" : ["open"]}],
    "table" : "",
    "show-top-bar" : true,
    "style_max-width" : "",
    "slideType" : "slide"
  },
  "method" : 106,
  "parName" : "A1519614709427",
  "formid" : "1"
}
```

**Model**

```
struct Params: Decodable {
  let parName: String, method: Int, callBackID: String
  let pageID: String?
  let fields: [String: Properties]?, filter: [String: Properties]?, table: String?
  let imageid: String?, imagetable: String?, appTemplate: String?, appName: String?, values: Properties?, columns: [String: Properties]?, formID: String?
  let config: [String]? (sample only, this line is invalid.)
}

struct Properties: Decodable {
  let source: String?, type: String?, rec_id: String?, name: String?, value: String?
}
```

Hi! With the data above, my objective is to print the values of "config". I know i can acheive this by creating more struct, but that's to many. Maybe there's a simple way.

print(param.config!)

```
"description" : "Welcome Page", "show-bottom-bar" : "", "css-page-align" : "", "footer" : { "show" : "", "object" : "bottom-bar" }, "pageStyle" : "full-page", "sourceType" : "list", "title" : "Welcome Page", "header" : { "show" : true, "hide" : false, "object" : "top-bar" }, "columns" : {}, "objects" : {}, "showtabs" : true, "slides" : [{"title" : "first section","map" : ["open"]}], "table" : "", "show-top-bar" : true, "style_max-width" : "", "slideType" : "slide"
```

how can i achieve this ^, thanks for your help :D

Comment: If you feel lazy, go to https://app.quicktype.io, paste in the JSON and let it generate the `Config` struct for you

Comment: @CodeDifferent thanks for the link but I'm not lazy to code all of the structures that i need, the purpose of my question is for educational and maybe there is someone who can share their techniques the shortest way to do with the struct. I can achieve this by using dictionary, but since im starting to use struct maybe theres a way... you know... and thanks again for the link i can share this with the other. :D